# Anyone know how to install Arial fonts on CentOs 7?

Tags: unix, centos, fonts, centos-7

I'm trying to install Arial fonts on CentOs 7 or a fonts pack containing such fonts, preferably using a yum command. I haven't found any guides on how to go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer. It's the same as CentOs 6.

http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-microsoft-truetype-fonts-in-centos-6-rhel-6.html

Steps below, in case the link ever stops working in future.

Switch to root user.

```
[geek@geeksite Desktop]$ su
Password:
```

Download the Microsoft core fonts rpm package.

```
[root@geeksite~/]# wget http://www.itzgeek.com/msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
```

Install rpm package.

```
[root@geeksite~/[# rpm -Uvh msttcore-fonts-2.0-3.noarch.rpm
That’s All.
```

Answer (score 3):

The [liberation fonts](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/) aim "at metric compatibility with Arial" and other Microsoft fonts, so `yum -y list | grep -i liberation` should turn up packages to install.

Answer (score 1):

Install `Arial` fonts for `CentOs`  with

```
  yum install curl cabextract xorg-x11-font-utils fontconfig
```

sourceforge is also a good choice:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mscorefonts2/files/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm/download?use_mirror=excellmedia